# Clipping multiple shapefiles using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, arcgis-pro, clip

I am fairly new to Python.

I created a folder with 4999 bufferfiles. Specifically, there 5km radius buffer circles, and I am trying to use the clip function with the already made bufferfiles to clip them to an environmental layerfile (called NPP2).

For the life of me I cannot figure out a way to dynamically import each of the 4999 bufferfiles into the clip function, specifically the `rectangle` variable.

```
#partially how I made bufferfiles/where they're stored  
randompoint = "randompoint_" + k  
bufferpoint = "buffer_" + k     
randompointbufferfile = bufferpoint + ".shp"  
randompointshapefile = randompoint + ".shp"  
shapedirectoryString = "C:\\Users\\72sno\\Documents\\RandomPython\\FixRandomPoints\\Slope\\ShapeFiles"  
bufferdirectoryString = "C:\\Users\\72sno\\Documents\\RandomPython\\FixRandomPoints\\Slope\\BufferFiles"   
full_path_shape = os.path.join(shapedirectoryString, randompointshapefile)  
full_path_buffer = os.path.join(bufferdirectoryString, randompointbufferfile)  
arcpy.analysis.Buffer(full_path_shape, full_path_buffer, "5 Kilometers", "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", None, "GEODESIC")

#Where I need help

#Access shapefile folder?  
aprx=arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r'C:\\Users\\72sno\\Documents\\ArcProjects\\Prairie.aprx')  
map = aprx.listMaps()[0]  
map.addDataFromPath("C:\\Users\\72sno\\Documents\\RandomPython\\FixRandomPoints\\Slope\\BufferFiles")  

#dynamically create 4999 clips  
clippoint = "clip_" + k  
clipdirectoryString = "C:\\Users\\72sno\\Documents\\RandomPython\\NPPRandomPoints2\\ClipFiles"   
full_path_clip = os.path.join(clipdirectoryString, clipoint)  
    
#How to add each 4999 buffer to the clip function (rectangle)???   
arcpy.management.Clip(r"C:\Users\72sno\Documents\RandomPython\NPP2.lyrx", rectangle, full_path_clip, full_path_buffer, "0", "ClippingGeometry", "MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

Comment: By "bufferfiles" I'm assuming you mean shapefiles created using the Buffer tool.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to list maps etc. and I dont think you can clip a lyrx.

Use ListFeatureClasses:

```
import os, arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\path\to\shapefilefolder'
featureclass_to_be_clipped = r'C:\data.gdb\features123'
out_folder= r'C:\outfolder'

for shapefile in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(): #List all shapefiles in env.workspace folder
    arcpy.analysis.Clip(in_features=featureclass_to_be_clipped, clip_features=shapefile, 
                        out_feature_class=os.path.join(out_folder, shapefile))
```